# Mutual Asymptotic analysis of the given fucntions

Tags: asymptotics

$ f(n)$ = $ 3n^{\sqrt{n}} $

$g(n)$ = $2^{\sqrt{n}log_2n}$

$h(n)=n! $

For all the $3$ pairs of the functions, which one is $Big-O$ of which ?

I am unable to compare these functions.

Edit : I plotted them and observed that for large $n$ :- $h(n)>f(n)>g(n)$

Comment: Are you familiar with Stirling's formula for the factorial? [if not, look it up!] Can you simplify $2^{\log_2n}$?

Comment: Ok. Let me study Stirling's formula.

Comment: So,$ g(n)$ = $ n^{\sqrt{n}}$ .

Comment: Right. So how do $f$ and $g$ compare?

Comment: Both are Big-O of each other.

Comment: $
    n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}. 
$
Dividing by $ n^{\sqrt{n}}$ we get $\sqrt{2 \pi n}(\frac1 {e^n}) \left({n}{}\right)^{n-\sqrt{n}}$ which is greater than $1$ for large $n$ (HOW?).

Comment: @GerryMyerson can you help me a little more(:P) with my above comment ?

Comment: It might be easier to see what goes on if you look at the logarithm of, say, $g$ and of the approximation you found for the factorial.

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write up what you know, and post it as an answer.